# Is placing "due to their usefulness" at the end of the passive voice form correct?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I need to convert the following sentence to passive voice:

> *Computers have gained popularity by their usefulness.*

**My attempt:**

*Popularity has been gained by computers due to their usefulness.*

However, this sentence sounds a bit awkward. Can it be improved?

Comment: Both versions are "awkward". It would be more normal to say something like *Computers have gained [in] popularity **because they are useful***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your sentence is not in passive voice.

Comment: Blue: As @James says in his answer, *there is absolutely no reason for the passive voice here*. I don't know why so many nns are so interested in recasting "natural" active voice statements into passive, but it doesn't seem to me to be a very useful party trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are rather awkward.  The problem seems to be the word "usefulness". I'd prefer "Computers have gained popularity by being useful", although a more fundamental re-writing could be better.

You wouldn't write that in the passive.

There is absolutely no reason for the passive voice here.

<sub>However, if your teacher is standing with a cane and a scowl, then "Popularity has been gained by computers by being useful"</sub>

<sub>You could also use "Popularity has been gained by computers due to their usefulness" and you would be understood.</sub>

But don't talk like that because while it is correct English, it is not *good* English.

Comment: Thanks. A query: Is "
Popularity has been gained by computers due to their usefulness." *wrong* English? I agree that it is not *good* English.

Comment: Not wrong. see edit.